# "new PDO" & __autoload function strange behaviour

Tags: php, pdo, autoload

I have made a __autoload function like this(in autoload.php):

```
function __autoload($name) {
    $arrName = explode('_', $name);
        $typename = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));
        $moduleName  = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));
    if(count($arrName) > 0 ){
        $className = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));  
    } else {
        $className = $moduleName;
    }   
    $location = '' . $typename . '/' . $moduleName . '/' . $className . '.php';
    include_once($location);
}
```

(I'm working with MVC(Model View Controller) structure).

And I'm calling a "new PDO"(in database.php):

```
private static $pdo;

        private static function getDB() {
            self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=something",'something','something');
            return self::$pdo;
        }
```

It gives me an error like this:

> Warning: include_once(pdo//.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   controller/autoload/autoload.php on line 15
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'pdo//.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   controller/autoload/autoload.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in
>   controller/core/database.php on line 7

I have tried using "new \PDO" but that doesn't change anything.
I also tried using "use PDO" but that gives me some more errors, maybe I use it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: PDO has no _, therefor you are array_shifting the P from PDO and lots of other issues with your autoloader. You might want to check whether $location is a file at all (`is_file()`) before including it. And return a true or false if it succeeds.

Comment: further more, do not forget to check if file_exist prior to include it

Comment: Thank you, This helped alot, the only problem I see now is class "PDO" not found..  but I will try to find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've explained what's going on in the comments:

```
// This gives array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "PDO" }
$arrName = explode('_', $name);

// This gives string(3) "pdo"
$typename = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));

// This gives string(0) ""
$moduleName  = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));

// This returns FALSE
if (count($arrName) > 0 )
{
  $className = strtolower(array_shift($arrName));  
}

else
{

  // This gives string(0) ""
  $className = $moduleName;

}

// This gives string(9) "pdo//.php"
$location = '' . $typename . '/' . $moduleName . '/' . $className . '.php';
```

However, as I assume you're using (or at least trying to use) the [`PHP Data Objects`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) extension, you need to make sure that it is [installed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I only have one error now:  Class 'PDO' not found. But I will do my best to solve it.